# Implementation of CQRS in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, cqrs

I am new to ADF and come from a .Net background.  My goal is to move towards a DDD for my application so that the code is encapsulated and represents my business processes.  That plan pushes me towards using CQRS to separate my Domain Models/Commands with the VOs used for query and display(possibly using ESS or SOA Components to push events to separate Data stores, but initially using a single DB).

I could not find any information on implementations of this in ADF, pros and cons, etc.

I would like to know:
Does what I am attempting makes sense in a ADF world?  Why/Why not? 
What challenges that may arise when using ADF in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand? I think you are over-engineering this. I would start with what ADF Architecture problems are you trying to solve with CQRS?

ADF has 4 "stacks" - ADF BC is the Data stack - EO/VOs based on tables/views and you can create VOs's based on web services if you need to integrate with SOA services ADF Faces is the server-generated UI Layer. ADF Controller handles page to page navigation. ADF Model is a data abstraction layer that sits between ADF BC and ADF Faces and allows for data movement and manipulation in the data layer by the view layer w/o direct connection - keeping the layers/tiers separate.

To manipulate a VO you either manipulate a Model Binding Iterator - which references the VO row set iterator and/or expose custom Java behaviors directly on the VO (not my chosen design) or on the Application Module (my choice) which can then be exposed to the UI via button/link or direct execution, while maintaining the separation of UI and Model and Data layer. 
All this code is generated and maintained for you by JDeveloper wizards and tooling and editors. So only custom code need be added.

So, ADF implements a form of Model-View-Controller design pattern.
I do not see what problem ADF presents that you want to solve by adding yet another layer of abstraction in CQRS.
.

Comment: I am trying to solve performance and code structure across a large organization.  What i am thinking of is more like separating the Command logic code, and having Fast Query VOs

Comment: Also, a lot of the processing is async and done via separate processors, so it is not really getting the benefit of a UI pattern in most of the processing.  Additionally i have a few patterns that cut across my entire project, so i want to abstract those and get good test coverage.